# Setting up a virtual environment for python3 using virtualenv on Ubuntu

Tags: django, python-3.x, ubuntu, virtualenv

I want to learn Django so for that, as per the instructions on the [website](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/contributing/), you need to create a virtual environment. I've heard enough horror stories about people corrupting their OS cause they didn't set up the virtual environments properly so it's safe to say I'm sufficiently paranoid.

I've created a separate folder/directory VirtualE at located at Academics/CS/VirtualENV and I want to create all my virtual environments there. As per the [website](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/contributing/), the following command should be used -

```
virtualenv --python=`which python3` ~/.virtualenvs/djangodev
```

I'm not sure what exactly I should write in place of the single quotes (the which python3 part). I wrote the following -

```
virtualenv --python=3.5.2 ~/Academics/CS/VirtualENV/DjangoDev
```

It says

```
The path 3.5.2 (from --python=3.5.2) does not exist
```

Where exactly am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you `cd` to the `Academics/CS/VirtualENV` folder....once inside the folder type `pwd`...then paste that output in your virtual env command..

Comment: @Hackerman same error

Comment: And with the command provided by @Heapify you have the full answer....that command tell you where python `lives`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the command line, type "which python3" and it will give you the path to python3. You just need to copy and paste that in the command. For example:

```
virtualenv --python=/path/to/python3/bin/python ~/Academics/CS/VirtualENV/DjangoDev
```